# how to insert user-defined button icons in intel XDK?

Tags: intel-xdk

I am using intel-XDK and I want to assign my own icons in the project.
How do I specify custom icons with the Intel XDK project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the "Projects" under "Launch icons and Splash Screens" you can supply images that will be used for those icons.  Each OS has different requirements for size and shape, but there are probably tools online that help generate them, given a starting point, e.g. https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/